# Dump prometheus data to parquet

Tags: python, dask, parquet

I'm trying to find the best practice when it comes to dumping prometheus data to parquet.
My data consists of known metric data monitored but unknown number of clients monitored being: VMs, Hosts, Pods, Containers, etc.

What I want first it to monitor all pods that have a fixed number of labels being tracked.

So I'm planning on structuring my data like this.

```
| ds                  | item   |   label_x |   label_n |   year |   month |   day |
|:--------------------|:-------|----------:|----------:|-------:|--------:|------:|
| 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | b      |        24 |        37 |   2020 |       6 |     1 |
| 2020-06-02 00:00:00 | b      |        17 |        37 |   2020 |       6 |     2 |
| 2020-06-03 00:00:00 | b      |        40 |        24 |   2020 |       6 |     3 |
| 2020-06-04 00:00:00 | b      |         1 |        22 |   2020 |       6 |     4 |
| 2020-06-05 00:00:00 | b      |        34 |         4 |   2020 |       6 |     5 |
```

Creating an `item` column for each `client` I have.

Then I'd save the next client which you come labeled as `c`.

```
| ds                  | item   |   label_x |   label_n |   year |   month |   day |
|:--------------------|:-------|----------:|----------:|-------:|--------:|------:|
| 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | c      |        24 |        22 |   2020 |       6 |     1 |
| 2020-06-02 00:00:00 | c      |        16 |        12 |   2020 |       6 |     2 |
| 2020-06-03 00:00:00 | c      |         1 |        18 |   2020 |       6 |     3 |
| 2020-06-04 00:00:00 | c      |         1 |        28 |   2020 |       6 |     4 |
| 2020-06-05 00:00:00 | c      |        45 |         4 |   2020 |       6 |     5 |
```

and just append them.

then to retrieve all items in a month for instance I could just:

```
filters = [('year', '==', 2020), ('month', '==', 6)]
ddf = dd.read_parquet(db, columns=['item'], filters=filters)
items = ddf[['item']].drop_duplicates().compute()
```

and grab an unique item by:

```
filters = [('item', '==', 'b'), ('year', '==', 2020), ('month', '==', 6)]
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Regards,
Carlos.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: if this is the right practice